# jquery to php same issue but specified

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, login-script

i am still having the same issue as before but this one is more specified and more info here's my form:

```
   <form method="post"action="">
   <table>
    <tr> <td>Login</td></tr>
    <tr><td> <input name="LEmail" id="LEmail" value="Email"/></td>
   <td> <label class="error" id="LEmail_error">*invalid</label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><input name="LPassword"  id="LPassword" value="Password"/></td>
   <td><label class="error" id="LPassword_error">*invalid</label>
  </td>
  </tr>
   </table>
  <input type="button" class="LButton" id="LButton" value="submit"/>
   </form>
```

and here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.error').hide(); 
    $(".LButton").click(function(){
        //alert("yay i was clicked");
        var LEmail=$("input#LEmail").val()
        if(LEmail==""||LEmail=="Email"){
            $("label#LEmail_error").show(); 
            return false; 
        }
        var LPassword=$("input#LPassword").val(); 
        if(LPassword==""||LPassword=="Password"){
            $("label#LPassword_error").show();
            return false; 
        }
        var info='LEmail='+ LEmail + '&LPassword=' + LPassword;
        alert(info);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"process.php",
            //dataType: string; 
            data: info,

            success:function(data){
                window.location.href="process.php";
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, type, exception){
            alert("something went wront here"); 
            alert("Error: " + type);
            console.log('@Error: '+errorThrown);
            console.log('@Status: '+status);
            console.log('@Status Text: '+xhr.statusText);
              }
        })
    });
});
```

and the php

```
   $LEmail=$_POST['LEmail']; 
    $LPassword=$_POST['LPassword'];
    /*
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT EmailAddress AND Password FROM Users WHERE EmailAddress=  $LEmail AND Password=$LPassword)>0){
    }
    */

    var_dump($LEmail);
    var_dump($LPassword);
```

for some reason when the php page loads it claims it is an undefined index LEMail same for LPassword

all my variables are NUM but when i do the alerts the values are correct

Comment: i am just trying to figure out why when i use ajax to pass it into a php file and then load the php file but when it loads it says undefined index LEmail and NULL values for my variables

Comment: does my question make sense now?

Comment: why are you using `var_dump` to display page?

Comment: Watch out for stuff like url-encoding. Why don't you just let jQuery do all the work for you and serialize your form instead of building the query on your own (which is very error-prone)? (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/): `var info = $('#form_id').serialize();` (so you'll have to give your form an id first). Also, make sure you've really set the right path to `process.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a url encode around the POST data values:

```
var info='LEmail='+ encodeURIComponent(LEmail) + '&LPassword=' + encodeURIComponent(LPassword);
```

If your POST data is not properly encoded, the PHP script will not be able to parse it.

**Edit**

I think this is the problem

```
        success:function(data){
            window.location.href="process.php";
            alert(data);
        },
```

When this happens your process.php has already processed the ajax call. You're calling it for a second time here, and obviously with a redirect like that there is no POST data and that is why you're seeing `undefined index` errors.

Comment: `urlencode()` is PHP. In JavaScript, it should be `encodeURIComponent()` ;)

Comment: @user1154295 As already said in the comments above, don't build this string manually, just give your form an ID and do a `var info = $('#form_id').serialize()` instead. It takes care of all this stuff for you. If it still does not work, track the request step by step. To do so, get FireBug (if you still don't have it installed) and check 1. if `process.php` is being found at all and 2. what data is send with the ajax-request.

Comment: thank you :-)  but i have tried that and it's still "unidentified index" and all the variables are null

Comment: it says array(2) {
  ["LEmail"]=>
  string(13) "test@test.com"
  ["LPassword"]=>
  string(7) "testing"
}
string(7) "testing" as response but the page still says the same thing as before

Comment: Thanks Quasdunk I've edited. @user1154295 what is shown in your `alert(info);` before the ajax call is made?

Comment: @user1154295 no problem - glad to have found the issue, feel free to accept the answer if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

1. On the server side do a `var_dump($_POST);` and see whats wrong.
2. Use firebug to double check the sent message (inspect the POST parameters you have sent).
3. Double check the whitespace in your `form` definition.
4. Serialize your form using jquery instead of manually building up your parameters.

Comment: when you say sent message do you mean input the variables in the alert?

Comment: @user1154295 Could it be that you call `process.php` *directly* in your browser to check the output? Because then, the `$_POST` array is definitely empty (of course, because you don't post anything). That would explain why (and where) you get the undefined-index-warning, but still get the correct data in your callback function when you call it with Ajax (as far as I understand)!

Comment: using firebug you can inspect the real request, sent from browser. then you can easily see where the error is: maybe your data is in the wrong part of the http message. could look like this: http://ifko.blog.matfyz.sk/firebug1.png